# dplyr left_join function incomplete joining, seemingly random NA's

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I have 2 dataframes I need to join.

One is from the EPA of cars and their fuel economy, the other is from a university database of parking permits. I need to reconcile and join the columns of the car year, make, and model which i have combined into a single column named 'join' on both df's.

When I do a left (or right) join, I get back a new df with the joined column of fuel economy for each parking permit-car. However, about 40% of columns come back as NA in the fuel-economy column. Sometimes this is due to discrepencies between the df's; "awd", "wagon", "Hybrid", etc. which I have accounted for, and gsub() out to simplify. This still doesn't account for all the NAs. Not sure how to make this reproducible w/o sharing the entire DF's, but I will show my code and examples of when it works, and doesn't.

```
     library(dplyr)
     library(plyr)

     epa <- as.tbl(epa) #make these df's tbl
     student <- as.tbl(student)

     joinedStudent <- right_join(epa, student, by = 'join')
```

.

Instances where this has worked:

"2013 Acura TL"

All Chevrolet Malibu models

.

Instances where I get an NA:

"2004 Acura TL"
All "Jeep" models

.

I have confirmed that the entries i.e. "2004 Acura TL" are identical to the entry in the epa df, no extra spaces, etc. There seems to be no pattern; it is not year specific, not make specific, the only pattern I can see is that no "Jeep" models of any year are joining.

Hopefully I'm missing something simple.

EDIT: The result was trailing spaces, even though I could not find or see any spaces in the df view pane. This was the code that fixed my issue

```
    #create function to remove trailing spaces
    trim.trailing <- function (x) sub("\\s+$", "", x)

    #apply function to remove trailing spaces
    epa$joined <- trim.trailing(epa$joined)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: so both epa and student have a column called "join" which you use as a joining index ?  the normal way would be to have some ID column to join by..

Comment: A few rows of each dataset would be helpful - are you able to show those, with any sensitive data removed?

Comment: @N.Bailey I tried reproducing it with a few lines of working / not working joins, and it worked in my reproduction... does this say something about one of the actual datasets im working with? I tried converting to tbl, leaving as regular df, as.factor(), as.character() no luck

Comment: @R.Prost "join" is the common name of the column of which I am joining the tables together.

Comment: If you can't make a small reproducible example, can you post a few lines of each dataset anyway?

Comment: @N.Bailey I edited the post to show my attempt at reproduction - in this case I dont get any NAs so its not reproducing my problem. Does this say somethign about my dataset im using?

Comment: @N.Bailey  here is a screencap of the df's im using. the left two are the ones im joining to create the third one. Notice the NAs and identical join columns: https://imgur.com/a/9wsGRWh

Comment: @R.Prost Here is a screencap of the df's im using. the left two are the ones im joining to create the third one. Notice the NAs and identical join columns: https://imgur.com/a/9wsGRWh

Comment: That's interesting. Are you importing the data from CSV files? Are you using read_csv? Are you specifying coltypes = ... ?

Comment: @N.Bailey yep, read_csv(), don't specify col types. However, I am creating my own column using:: epa$join <- paste(epa$year, epa$make,epa$model)
for both epa and student df's to make a single column that is unique

Comment: Don't do that - just pass multiple variables to left_join or right_join, as a vector: `left_join(epa, student, by = c("year", "make", "model"))` This may not fix your problem, but is easier to understand :)

Comment: @N.Bailey unfortunately I get a very similar result... this is driving me crazy.

Comment: Try this: `print(bind_rows(epa %>% distinct(join), student %>% distinct(join)) %>% arrange(join))` Maybe you have some pesky additional white space or something somewhere.

Comment: @N.Bailey what is the purpose of that code?

Comment: holy shit i think i got it. It did have to do w/ trailing spaces. I used: trim.trailing <- function (x) sub("\\s+$", "", x)

epa$joined <- trim.trailing(epa$joined)

Comment: @N.Bailey post that in the solutions and ill check mark you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pointed out by @N.Bailey. It had to do with phantom spaces trailing in a column of data; I couldn't even highlight the spaces to notice them.

```
     trim.trailing <- function (x) sub("\\s+$", "", x) 
     epa$joined <- trim.trailing(epa$joined)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print(bind_rows(epa %>% distinct(join), student %>% distinct(join)) %>% arrange(join))
```

Maybe you have some pesky additional white space or something somewhere - this code should help you spot it.